# Separating multiple values by comma in database, and printing to PDF with FPDF using foreach

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, fpdf

I'm sorry if this question is poorly explained, but I don't really know how to ask it. I'm new to FPDF and I'm trying to generate a PDF file, with some values from a database. When the user inserts values to the table, they have a choice if they want to put multiple lines into the same column. If so, the 2 different values in the database are separated by `\n\n`. Then in FPDF, I want it do print out every value, when it notices the `\n\n` (new-lines). Check code below.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($row as $row) {
    $pdf->Write(5, numberToRomanRepresentation($i).".");
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(35);
    $pdf->SetRightMargin(35);
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',12);
    $pdf->Write(5, $row['law_broken']);
    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $i += $i;
}
```

I've tried looking up how to "notice" the new-lines with `explode(",", $row['law_broken'])` but with no luck. Is there any hope out here for me?

Thanks

EDIT 1:

Changed the code to look like this:

```
$i = 1;
$row2['law_broken'] = explode(', ', $row2['law_broken']);
foreach ($result as $row2) {
    $pdf->Write(5, numberToRomanRepresentation($i).".");
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(35);
    $pdf->SetRightMargin(35);
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',12);
    $pdf->Write(5, $row2['law_broken']);
    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $i += $i;
}
```

Also changed the values in the database to be separated by comma instead of `\r\n`
Still no luck though.

Comment: Are the new lines separated by a comma or by `\n` or perhaps `\r\n`? Your comment says `\n` but your explode is using a comma.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I have indeed changed it from being ```\r\n``` to a simple comma.

Comment: What happens if you leave the `\r\n` in and don't try to change it? Oh and BTW you should be able to explode based on the `\r\n`.

Comment: I know I can. I changed it to a simple comma because it's easier for the user to separate multiple values with a comma instead. I have changed the code a bit, look at updated question. Still no luck though. Only printing the the whole column at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result of the `explode` is an array you need to loop through each of the elements output each one. You will likely need to adjust the positioning of the lines but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
foreach ($result as $row2) {
    $pdf->Write(5, numberToRomanRepresentation($i).".");
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(35);
    $pdf->SetRightMargin(35);
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','BU',12);
    $law_broken = explode(', ', $row2['law_broken']);
    foreach ($law_broken as $lawline) {
        $pdf->Write(5, $lawline);
        $pdf->Ln(5);
    }  // end of foreach through each of the law_broken entries
}  // end of foreach through the results
```

Comment: Looks like I'm making some progress, this is probably exactly what I needed. Just need to make some final tweaks, and check if it all still works! :) Thanks!

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Comment: I have now tweaked it, and it works perfectly! Thanks! :)